# regarding tf.nn.conv1d and its corresponding transpose operation

Tags: tensorflow

In the latest tensorflow version, there is [tf.nn.conv2d_transpose](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/conv2d_transpose) for the 2D deconvolution operation. However, there is no corresponding 1D deconvolution operation for [tf.nn.conv1d](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/conv1d). How to perform the deconvolution for 1D data?

Answer (score 1):

Well, `conv1d` is actually `conv2d` with `in_height=1`. The [nn_ops.py.conv1d](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.4/tensorflow/python/ops/nn_ops.py) states:

```
Internally, this op reshapes the input tensors and invokes `tf.nn.conv2d`. 
For example, if `data_format` does not start with "NC", a tensor of shape
  [batch, in_width, in_channels]
is reshaped to
  [batch, 1, in_width, in_channels],
and the filter is reshaped to
  [1, filter_width, in_channels, out_channels].
The result is then reshaped back to
  [batch, out_width, out_channels]
\(where out_width is a function of the stride and padding as in conv2d\) and
 returned to the caller.
```

Thus, `tf.nn.conv2d_transpose` can do the job.